# What is None doing in the code object's co_consts attribute?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals

The following function returns `None`:

```
In [5]: def f():
   ...:     pass
```

So I was not surprised by this output:

```
In [8]: dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        

In [10]: f.__code__.co_consts
Out[10]: (None,)
```

Ok, this makes sense. But now, consider the following function:

```
In [11]: def g():
   ....:     return 1

In [12]: dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        

In [13]: g.__code__.co_consts
Out[13]: (None, 1)
```

`g` does not use `None`, so why is it in `co_consts`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default return value for a function is `None`, so it is always inserted. Python doesn't want to have to analyse if you are *always* going to reach a return statement.

Consider for example:

```
def foo():
    if True == False:
        return 1
```

The above function will return `None`, but only because the `if` statement is never going to be `True`.

In your simple case, it is obvious to us humans that there is just the one `RETURN_VALUE` opcode, but to extend this to the general case for a computer to detect is not worth the effort. Better just store the `None` reference and be done with it, that one reference is *extremely cheap*.